# Issue with Ambassador Mapping

Tags: kubernetes, ambassador

[image]I am going through this [tutorial](https://www.getambassador.io/docs/latest/tutorials/quickstart-demo/) .My ambassador end point is not setting up after using this command

```
export AMBASSADOR_LB_ENDPOINT=$(kubectl -n ambassador get svc ambassador -o "go-template={{range .status.loadBalancer.ingress}}{{or .ip .hostname}}{{end}}")
```

If I try to print `echo $AMBASSADOR_LB_ENDPOINT` it returns empty. `kubectl get svc` gave me below output.
Any idea what's wrong with my configuration.

Comment: Which K8s cluster are you using ? When you list the services `kubectl get svc ` what do you see for the Ambassador LoadBalancer ?

Comment: @AvinashKumar I have updated my question. I am using Kubernetes.

Comment: This is not an issue with Ambassador service but with your k8s cluster..The external-IP is pending, hence AMBASSADOR_LB_ENDPOINT is empty as the LoadBalancer IP is empty..    
One more thing you are checking the IP of svc `kubectl get svc ambassador` , I don't see ambassador svc in your list of services.

Comment: @AvinashKumar It's got solved.Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was problem regarding Minikube. It got solved.

I followed the steps given [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/expose-external-ip-address/)